# How to use Inner Join with Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I have a query in SQL that need convert to lambda expression, but I'm not sure how to use the WHERE function.

This is my query in SQL:

SELECT * FROM tickets t
INNER JOIN groups g on t.GroupId = g.GroupId 
WHERE g.UserId = 4 AND t.StatusId = 3 OR t.UserCreatedBy = 4 AND t.StatusId = 3

I tried to convert it of the following way:

```
var query = db.Tickets
.Include(t => t.CftGroup)
.Include(t => t.Customer)
.Include(t => t.Factory)
.Include(t => t.Failure)
.Include(t => t.Line)
.Include(t => t.Priority)
.Include(t => t.Process.ProcessGroup)
.Include(t => t.Site)
.Include(t => t.Status)
.Join(db.Groups, t => t.CftGroupId, g => g.CftGroupId, (t, g) => new
{
    userCreatedBy = t.UserCreatedBy,
    userId = g.UserId,
    statusId = t.StatusId
})
.Where(
x => x.userId == id
&& x.statusId != Closed
|| x.userCreatedBy = id
&& x.statusId != Closed
);
```

Comment: What isn't working with the `where` clause?

Comment: You tried, great! But what's the result?

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Comment: Why does your LINQ have `x.statusID != Closed` but your SQL have `t.StatusId = 3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These worked fine with me:

```
  var TicketList =   Tickets
    .Join( Groups,
         ticket => ticket.GroupID,
         group => group.ID,
         (customer , group ) => new { Ticket = ticket, Group = group})
.Where(x => x.Group.UserId == 4 && (x.Ticket.StatusId == 3 || x.Ticket.UserCreatedBy == 4) && x.Ticket.StatusId == 3)
         .Select(select => select.Ticket ).ToList();
```